# Restrict gitea access with roles in keycloak

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, roles, gitea

I'm using gitea (1.8.3) and now I want to use it in connection with keycloak and OpenID connect.
The basic communication works so far and it is possible to register and log in with keycloak.

Now I'm trying to allow the connection only for users with the specific role "gitea_user". The user gets the role by his group. I tried around a lot with authorization configs, permissions, etc. but it is always possible for every user in the client to log in or register on gitea. My question is, what do I have to consider in the settings of keycloak (or whatever)?

I'm still new to keycloak and gitea and maybe I miss something big in the hole system. So far I didn't find any example for this and the docs are not really helpful to me.

Thanks for every hint!

Comment: Wondering if you found any answers elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you need to sync the groups from keycloak into gitea, maybe with something like https://github.com/PrehensileTales/gitea-sync

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).